# Animation on hover

Tags: css, animation

Having a slight problem with some CSS3 animations.

On the main navigation that runs below the header, which starts with About and ends on Contact and Downloads. When I hover over the li's the animation plays again. Which is not what I want to happen. I would like to play initially when page loads - that's it.

Here is the link: http://wilkins.epixdev1.co.uk/

and here's the CSS code:

```
-webkit-animation-name: slideDown;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: once;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;   
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
-moz-animation-name: slideDown;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: once;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;   
-moz-animation-delay: 3s;
animation-name: slideDown;
animation-iteration-count: once;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-delay: 3s;
```

And here are the keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideDown {0% {top: -59px;} 100% {top: 0px;}}
@-moz-keyframes slideDown {0% {top: -59px;} 100% {top: 0px;}}
@-o-keyframes slideDown {0% {top: -59px;} 100% {top: 0px;}}
@-ms-keyframes slideDown{0% {top: -59px;} 100% {top: 0px;}}
@keyframes slideDown {0% {top: -59px;} 100% {top: 0px;}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove these css lines ( start on line 211 )

```
#access li:hover    {
-webkit-animation:none;
-moz-animation:none;
-o-animation:none;
-ms-animation:none;
animation:none;
}
```

-webkit-animation-iteration-count: once; is invalid, but it's default to 1, so when the animatio finished, it won't start again, and I think animation:none will break this and reset the animation.

Answer (score 1):

i think there's a problem in your `style.css`:

```
#access li:hover    {
-webkit-animation:none;
-moz-animation:none;
-o-animation:none;
-ms-animation:none;
animation:none;
}
```

Set the animation to none at hover the outer `li` but then it get's release by going on the inner Elements.
So it roll back to the normal animation and do it again once ;)

Answer (score 0):

**remove** this style from your CSS:

```
#access li:hover {
-webkit-animation: none;
-moz-animation: none;
-o-animation: none;
-ms-animation: none;
animation: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IMHO css3 `animation` cannot be run on hover. Isn't it some other type of effect? Css3 `transtion` or some javascript?